# awk, sed: one liner command for removing spaces from _all_ file names in a given folder?

Tags: sed, awk, command

Before:

```
eng-vshakya:scripts vshakya$ ls
American Samoa.png                  Faroe Islands.png                   Saint Barthelemy.png
```

After:

```
eng-vshakya:scripts vshakya$ ls
AmericanSamoa.png                   FaroeIslands.png                    SaintBarthelemy.png
```

Tried below prototype, but it does not work :( Sorry, not very good when it comes to awk/sed :(

```
ls *.png | sed 's/\ /\\\ /g' | awk '{print("mv "$1" "$1)}'
```

[ Above is prototype, real command, I guess, would be:

```
ls *.png | sed 's/\ /\\\ /g' | awk '{print("mv "$1" "$1)}' | sed 's/\ //g'
```

]

Comment: This suffers from the [Parsing ls problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  Use ghoti's solution instead, if your shell supports it.

Comment: @Graham: I was not aware of Parsing ls problem. Link was very useful. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ghoti's solution is the right thing to do.  Since you ask how to do it in sed, here's one way:

```
for file in *; do newfile=$( echo "$file" | tr -d \\n | sed 's/ //g' );
   test "$file" != "$newfile" && mv "$file" "$newfile"; done
```

The `tr` is there to remove newlines in the filename, and is necessary to ensure that sed sees the entire filename in one line.

Answer (score 18):

No need to use awk or sed when you can do this in pure bash.

```
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp1]$ ls -l
total 2
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  wheel  0 Aug  1 01:19 American Samoa.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  wheel  0 Aug  1 01:19 Faroe Islands.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  wheel  0 Aug  1 01:19 Saint Barthelemy.png
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp1]$ for name in *\ *; do mv -v "$name" "${name// /}"; done
American Samoa.png -> AmericanSamoa.png
Faroe Islands.png -> FaroeIslands.png
Saint Barthelemy.png -> SaintBarthelemy.png
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp1]$
```

Note that the `${foo/ /}` notation is **bash**, and does not work in classic Bourne shell.

Comment: thanks for the answer. and although i understand this is the right way to do, but the intention to ask this question was more for my personal learning and not be a part of any production systems. so i'm accepting Mr Pursell's answer.